# using arrays for type resolution

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to have the following function signature:

```
type fn = <T>(fields : (keyof T)[]) => { [key in fields] : any }
```

Which would produce type checks as follows

```
const StructureType = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}

// the fields argument is strictly type checked
// this fails because c not in keyof T
const x = fn<typeof StructureType>(['c'])

// this works
const x = fn<typeof StructureType>(['a'])
// x should be of type = { a : any }
// function parameter
```

If you chain the generics it can work, but then you have to manually pass multiple generic types

```
type fn = <T, TField extends keyof T>(fields : TField[]) => { [key in TField] : any }

// cannot call like this, throws error missing arguments
const x = fn<StructureType>(['a'])
```

If you pass the type as an argument, you can eliminate the generic defs, but then you're passing an unused parameter to the function:

```
type fn = <T, TField extends keyof T>(structType : T, fields : TField[]) => { [key in TField] : any }

// works
const x = fn(StructureType, ['a'])
```

Another way that I've found works is to chain functions together:

```
type fn = <T>() => <TField extends keyof T>(fields : TField[]) => { [key in TField] : any }

// this works
const x = fn<StructureType>()(['a'])
```

But obviously this isn't the best solution, as it's creating an unnecessary extra function.

Is there a way to achieve what I want without making extra, unneeded code?